# Median value within polygon of a data layer like NDVI- iterate over multiple polygons defined in map interface

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, polygon, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a script below that will calculate the median NDVI for any polygon, store it, and chart it for export, over a range of dates.  The script also performs some cloud masking prior to NDVI calculation which seems to be helpful since it removes some erratic swings in NDVI for certain dates especially during rainy season.

How can I create a set of polygons (could also be polygons in an uploaded shapefile) and then iterate the script across all the polygons to be able to create a multi-line chart, and more importantly, download or export a table/CSV with multiple time-courses of median NDVI?

Right now the variable 'quilcas_med' identifies the polygon in the zonal statistics function for median value of the polygon; I need to build a loop around this where I turn this single polygon into a polygon indexed by the loop rep -- and basically I'm lacking the skills in JavaScript/ GEE to do this.  What would be best for now is to be able to produce a layer of multiple polygons in the map interface of GEE and then if these had separate ids, iterate over them.  Since I think an imported shapefile could take the same form (multiple polygons in a layer) it would also work for that.

L5 is surface reflectance, tier one, collection 2, Landsat 5 data
'Quilcas' is a roi point in the Peruvian Andes for finding scenes, but could be anywhere
'quilcas_med' within the function MedianRegion is a polygon in the same area, but again could be anywhere, polygon or multipolygon

```js
// Applies scaling factors.

function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}
    
var filtered = L5.filterDate('1984-5-09', '2011-12-31')
. filterBounds(Quilcas); 

// cloud masking function pulled from internet

function maskL457sr(image) {

  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Unused
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow

  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.

  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.

  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBand, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

// Map the function over the time period filtered above

var L5_cloudfree = filtered
            .map(maskL457sr);
                     
// false color scheme for easily visualizing agricultural areas in map for adjusting polygon areas

var falsecolor = {
  bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3' ],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

// check cloudfree layer after masking of pixels - comment in when needed

Map.addLayer(L5_cloudfree, falsecolor, 'CloudFree_falseColor');

// Map.addLayer(filtered, falsecolor, 'FalseColor (321)');
// Map.addLayer(filtered.median(), falsecolor, 'RGB - median reducer');
// Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'NDVI');

// function to add NDVI band to collection of images

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
    }
    
var with_ndvi = L5_cloudfree.map(addNDVI);

var ndvi_qlmed = with_ndvi
  .filterBounds(Quilcas)

// function for calculating zonal statistics pulled from internet, change to 
// mean(), median () etc. as needed

var MedianRegion = function(image) {

  // This regionReduction returns a dictionary; in this case a single key-value
  // pair for the mean summary of NDVI and the date of the imagery

  var medianNDVI = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    geometry: quilcas_med,
    scale: 30,
    bestEffort: true});

  // Along with mean NDVI for the region (renamed), add some info about the image
  // that mean NDVI is based on (the image ID and the image date). Define these
  // attributes in a dictionary.

  var props = {
    'medianNDVI': medianNDVI.get('nd'),
    'imgID': image.id(),
    'date': image.date().format('MM-dd-YYYY')};

  // Return the information as a feature, so that the result of mapping this
  // function over a collection will be another collection that can be cast as
  // a featureCollection, which can be exported to Google Drive or plotted. Use the 'geom'
  // to defined the feature's geometry, and the 'props' dictionary to define the
  // properties of the feature.

  return ee.Feature(quilcas_med, props);
};

var L5_reduceRegion = ee.FeatureCollection(ndvi_qlmed.map(MedianRegion));

// Export. commented out for troubleshooting and further adaptation
//   collection: l5_reduceRegion,
//   description: 'l5_reduceRegion',
//   folder: 'reduce_region_test',
//   fileFormat: 'CSV'});

//  print the feature collection if needed to examine features for debugging
//  print(L5_reduceRegion)

// produce graph of median (or mean etc.) NDVI for polygon or multi-polygon across
// range of dates

  var outgraph = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(L5_reduceRegion, 'date', 'medianNDVI');
  print(outgraph);
```